# Se puede hacer el fondo de un progressbar transparente o dar algun color?

Tags: c#, progressbar

Se puede hacer esto en C#?
Tiene algo que ver con el borderstyle?

[image: Imagen de referencia]

Comment: Eso es Winforms, con C# o Visual Basic, en todo caso lo podes hacer con cualquier que puedas acceder a la propiedad del ProgressBar

Comment: Es C#, Cual seria el atributo que permite que esto sea posible? he estado revisando las propiedades del progressbar pero no consigo quitarselo...

Comment: Seguramente tenes que customizar el componente y es algo que en WinForms nunca realice. Pero deberias buscar como hacer un custom de un componente, pero si recien arrancas con esto, quizas seria mas complicado de entender.

Comment: Esta en chino la documentacion sobre como crear un nuevo progressbar x_x

Comment: no, debes buscar en la pagina de microsoft, ahi esta toda la documentacion sobre sus plataformas y lenguajes